# Visual Studio installer doesn't generate 'Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0' compiler folder

Tags: qt, installation, visual-studio-2017

I want to use the Visual C++ 2015 & Visual C++ 2017 compilers for a Qt project, and thus downloaded the Microsoft Studio 2019 Community installer from the Microsoft official website to install them.

I followed the steps described in this forum's main reply: https://forum.qt.io/topic/78962/how-to-use-qt-with-visual-studio-2017/12, and added individual components to install Visual 2015 as well (sorry for the french installer, hope the component names are understandable) :

[image: Visual Studio 2019 installer]

The installation process generates a 'Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0' folder (in which Visual C++ 2015 files are) but no 'Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0' folder for Visual C++ 2017:

[image]

Moreover, Qt Creator finds the Visual C++ 2015 compiler in **Tools -> Options -> Kits -> Compiler** and compilation with it works fine, but Qt can't the Visual C++ 2017 compiler:

[image]

Thanks for any solution.

Comment: Did you try a restart after you installed the 2017 tool-chain?

Comment: Hi Vince, "but no 'Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0' folder for Visual C++ 2017:" for the VS 2017/2019, the installation folder is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio" not 15.0 as before, please open VS 2019 and create a new C++ console project, right click the project name and choose 'Properties', click the dropdown list of 'Platform Toolset' to check the installed C++ build tools to confirm the VS installation works fine or not.

Comment: @Zlatomir Yes, but Qt still can't find VS 2017.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT Visual Studio IDE can find the compiler since it gives me the choice between VS 2015/2017/2019 in the 'Platform Toolset' menu. Does it mean Qt can't find the compiler because of a path issue ?

Comment: update: after reinstallation of Qt for a more recent version, it finds both VS 2015 and VS 2019 in the compiler panel, but still not VS 2017. VS2019 is found at repertory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat'

Comment: @Vince, thanks for your update and sorry for the delay reply, if you manually config and locate the VS 2017 C++ compiler, QT can detect it or not?

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT, thank you for your answers. To be honnest, I don't know where VS 2017 is located. In 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\', there's only 3 folders: 2019, Installer, Shared. I try to search 'vcvarsall.bat' (which is linked to the compiler i believe) in 'C:\' but it only returns me the one from VS 2019, not even the one in VS 2015 folder (for some reason), so I doubt I'll find anything this way.